# Counting the occurrences of a distinct values depending on its date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct

I am trying to find a SQL Server query that will find distinct values in a particular column, count the number of occurrences of that value depending on its date.

Example data:

```
in_date     item_code       
---------   ---------
2015/11/25  item1
2015/11/25  item2
2015/12/10  item1
2015/12/10  item1
2015/12/10  item2
2016/01/01  item1
```

Expected output:

```
Date          Item1     Item2
----------    -----     -----
2015/11/25    1         1
2015/12/10    2         1
2016/01/01    1         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
Select 
  in_date, 
  Sum (case when item_code = item1 then 1 else 0 end) item1,
  Sum (case when item_code = item2 then 1 else 0 end) item2
From tbl
Group by in_date
```